# Custom table of contents based on a model

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, section-titles

I’m converting an oldish book into tex and I need to mimic a weird table of contents (picture here after), but I do not find any suitable models to start working with. I used the following structure (as in the picture): high-level titles (INTRODUCTION, FORM) are considered as sections, then you have chapters and then finally you have the subsections under each chapter (see code here after). Any advice on where to begin and what package to use?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=9.250in:6.125in,pagesize,
twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Preface}
\sectionmark{Preface}
\newpage
\section{INTRODUCTION}
\sectionmark{Introduction}
\newpage
\chapter{Comparative Biology: Space, Time, and Form}
\chaptermark{Comparative Biology}
\subsection{The Science of Comparative Biology}
\subsection{Problems of Form: Systematics}
\subsection{Problems of Time: Ontogeny and Paleontology}
\subsection{Problems of Space; Biogeography}
\section{FORM}
\sectionmark{Form}
\newpage
\chapter{Systematic History: Kinds of Branching Diagrams}
\chaptermark{Systematic History}
\subsection{Natural Kinds}
\subsection{Stability of Classification}
\newpage
\chapter{Systematic Patterns: Component Analysis}
\chaptermark{Systematic Patterns}
\subsection{Cladograms, Trees, and Components}
\subsection{Cladograms and Information}
\subsection{Trees and Information}
\subsection{A Postscript on Parsimony}
\subsection{Information, Phyletics, and Phenetics}
\subsection{Information and Components}
\subsection{Incomplete Information, Multiple Branching, and Reticulation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer but something to help you along. The following MWE, which is based on the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) produces a ToC that in general looks like what you are after.

```
% weirdtocprob.tex SE 633903

\documentclass{memoir}

%%% this is a revision from the .sty file for memoir
%%% but I can't remember just how it worked
%%% list sections in ToC as a paragraph
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setupparasecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline
  \renewcommand*{\cftsectionfont}{\upshape}
  \renewcommand*{\cftsectionpagefont}{\upshape}
  \renewcommand{\l@section}[2]{
    \ifnum\c@tocdepth > 0\relax
    \def\numberline####1{\textup{####1}~}%
    \leftskip=\cftsectionindent
    \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
    \parfillskip=\fill
    \ifhmode \llap{,}\ \else\noindent\fi
    \ignorespaces
        {\cftsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsectionpagefont##2}%
        \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces
        \fi}
  }

  \makeatother

  \setupparasecs

\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter }

\renewcommand{\thesection}{}  %% no section numbers
  \begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents
  \mainmatter
  \addtocontents{toc}{\centering INTRODUCTION \par}
  \chapter{First chapter}
  \section{One section}
  \section{Two section}
  \section{Three section}
  \newpage
  \section{Another}
  \section{And another with a longer title}
  \section{One more and let's see how this is in the ToC}

  \end{document}
```

It is up to you to modify the divisional (chapter/section) code in your document to provide the appropriate commands to the ToC.

**EDIT -- ADDED A GRAPHIC**

[image]